# custom spinner with colored dropdown image

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am working with custom spinner. I am struggle on this.
[image]

How can I get the spinner like this ?
Note : I have the red color image.

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-get-holo-spinner-theme-in-android-2-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API 21, you can use [widget tinting](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#widget-tinting) feature, most widgets (spinner included) will follow your `colorAccent`.

For lower APIs, you can apply custom drawable. Check [android-holor-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) for a quick generation of your widget drawable. In your case, check 'Spinner' or 'Colored Spinner'.

Comment: Its nice. Time saving too. And I hope if there is a small step by step guide it will help others sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Custom adapters.

You can design how a row of your spinner looks like.

The link bellow will help you.

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

Comment: is this related to work with theme? could anyone give example to how to do this ?